# AssertJ Swing occasional test failure

Tags: java, swing, assertj

## Context

I got an **AssertJ-Swing (3.9.2) test** giving me headaches, **sometimes** it fails with a ComponentLookupError declaring that the entire component hierarchy is empty. This is the [exact scenario of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338739/why-do-we-get-occasional-failures-in-assertj-swing-tests), with the addition **that I'm using VNC on my Travis istance.**

The interesting part: failures are concentrated only on this particular test, hosted in a class of two test classes for JDialog implementations of an abstract class.

- **[TodoDialog](https://github.com/rickie95/todolist/blob/develop/com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist/src/main/java/com/riccardomalavolti/apps/todolist/view/TodoDialog.java)**: abstract class
- **[NewTodoDialog](https://github.com/rickie95/todolist/blob/develop/com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist/src/main/java/com/riccardomalavolti/apps/todolist/view/NewTodoDialog.java)** and **[EditTodoDialog](https://github.com/rickie95/todolist/blob/develop/com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist/src/main/java/com/riccardomalavolti/apps/todolist/view/EditTodoDialog.java)** implements **TodoDialog**. They do a very similar job, hence the abstract class. I started assembling the UI in a `initFrame` method in `TodoDialog`, but then I erased it and replicate the code in both the constructors of the implementated classes since I guessed could be the cause of the test behavior.

## The incriminated test

The strange behavior is shown on
`NewTodoDialogTest.testClearTagsShouldRestoreTagLabel`, [NewTodoDialogTest](https://github.com/rickie95/todolist/blob/develop/com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist/src/test/java/com/riccardomalavolti/apps/todolist/view/NewTodoDialogTest.java) other tests are doing fine, no problems at all.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.404 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist.view.NewTodoDialogTest
[ERROR] testClearTagsShouldRestoreTagLabel(com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist.view.NewTodoDialogTest)  Time elapsed: 0.727 s  <<< ERROR!
org.assertj.swing.exception.ComponentLookupException: 
Unable to find component using matcher org.assertj.swing.core.NameMatcher[name='tagComboBox', type=javax.swing.JComboBox, requireShowing=true].

Component hierarchy:
com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist.view.NewTodoDialog[name='dialog1', title='New To Do ', enabled=true, modal=false, visible=true, showing=true]

        at com.riccardomalavolti.apps.todolist.view.NewTodoDialogTest.testClearTagsShouldRestoreTagLabel(NewTodoDialogTest.java:146)
```

That's the test's code:

```
    @Test @GUITest
    public void testClearTagsShouldRestoreTagLabel() {
        // Selecting an element
        window.comboBox("tagComboBox").selectItem(0);
        assertThat(window.comboBox("tagComboBox").selectedItem()).isEqualTo("Bar");
        assertThat(window.label("tagLabel").text()).isEqualTo("(Bar)");

        // Click on Clear Tag
        window.button("clearButton").click();
        assertThat(window.label("tagLabel").text()).isEqualTo(NewTodoDialog.TAG_LBL_NO_TAG_TEXT);
        assertThat(window.comboBox("tagComboBox").selectedItem()).isNull();
    }
```

I've tried to use Awatility, setting an await for the panel/label/button, but that not worked and this have sense to me, since other tests (which interact with the same components) are doing fine. I've tried to use a script to execute the tests on vnc also on my local machine but it frozed KDE.

Anyone has some ideas? It's a very tricky issue.