# How to fix AssertJ Swing tests that are passing locally but failing in a CI server?

Tags: java, swing, continuous-integration, assertj, gui-testing

My GUI unit-tests with Assertj Swing (version 3.17.0) all pass locally, but sometimes they fail in a CI server. If i retry long enough, eventually the test suite becomes green. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fix these tests.

I am using Java 8 and Github Actions as CI. As suggested in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048892/6022481), I am using VNC to run these tests headlessly on CI, with the command:

```
./execute-on-vnc.sh mvn -B -f pom.xml clean verify
```

Here's an example of a test that is failing (I am mocking the controller and just verifying that clicking a button actually calls the controller method with the correct arguments):

```
@Mock private ItemController controller;

@Test @GUITest
public void testAddItemButtonShouldDelegateToControllerAddItem() {
    window.textBox("itemIdTextField").enterText("1");
    window.textBox("itemNameTextField").enterText("Some Item");
    window.button(JButtonMatcher.withName("addItemButton")).click();
    verify(controller).addItem(new Item("1", "Some Item"));
}
```

Here's the very straight forward code for handling clicks on the JButton:

```
addItemButton.addActionListener(e ->
    controller.addItem(new Item(itemIdTextField.getText(), itemNameTextField.getText()))
);
```

The test passes locally every time with no issues, but often fails on CI with this error:

```
testAddItemButtonShouldDelegateToControllerAddItem(com.example.view.swing.ItemSwingViewTest)
Time elapsed: 0.985 sec  <<< FAILURE!
Wanted but not invoked:

controller.addItem(
  Item{id='1', name='Some Item'}
);

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I have not been able to figure out the cause of these flaky tests.

Things I've tried:

- Added 5 seconds timeouts to verify() methods
- Invalidated CI maven cache and rerun tests
- Tested on CI with other Java versions (9, 11 and 13)

All with no luck. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm working on your same problem, maybe the problem it is that in Github action it not allowed the UI rendering?

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758763/swing-ui-tests-on-github-actions