# Swing UI tests on Github Actions

Tags: java, swing, github-actions, xvfb

I have a few UI tests for my Java application made with AssertJ-Swing and JUnit 5. I encounter no problem running these tests locally but some of the tests fail once I push them to my continuous integration on Github Actions.

The `.yml` looks like this:

```
...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      workdir: idTest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: > 
        xvfb-run mvn verify
      working-directory: ${{ env.workdir }}
```

As you can see I'm using `xvfb-run` to run the tests headlessly and for my simple tests that should be enough.

Dumb example test that (sometimes) fails because the item is not selected:

```
@Test
@GUITest
void test() {

    Item item = new Item("name");
    GuiActionRunner.execute(() -> view.getListModel().addElement(item));

    window.list("list").selectItem(0);
    window.list("list").requireSelectedItems(0);
}
```

The "strange" thing is that sometimes the test passes and sometimes it doesn't. It happens also with `click()` on buttons.
I've also tried running the tests under Windows (that needs no `xvfb` to run) on Github Actions with no problems, so I guess that `xvfb` is the issue here.
Anyone knows what the problem might be? I'm also up for trying different solutions other than `xvfb` if anyone has any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: As I know, AssertJ-Swing is very unstable when running on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyMedvynskyy I've also tried running the tests locally on Ubuntu a dozen of times, and had no problems there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my view class I had something like this:

```
public class MyView extends JFrame{
    private CardLayout layout;
    private JPanel myPane;
        
    public MyView() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("View");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        layout = new CardLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        myPane = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(myPane, "pane");

        layout.show(getContentPane(), "layout");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    }
}
```

Removing the last three lines fixed it for me. I suppose that they were interfering with `xvfb`. Also it seems that they add no value to the code itself and it is safe to remove them.